# Does modulus while loop have a different outcome when in while loop?

Tags: javascript

I ran into this question on sololearn.. Why is the answer 36 and not 6?

```
var x = 326;

var prod = 1;

while (x>0) {
    prod *= x%10;
    x = (x-x%10)/10;
    }

 console.log(prod);
```

Comment: Why don't you debug it, add some logs in the loop, figure it out, and tell us?

Comment: console.log() is your friend....

Comment: No, modulus does not have a different outcome if it is placed in a while loop.

Comment: is iteration p =6 2nd p=12 3rd iteration p=36

Answer (score 2):

This line takes the last digit of the `x` variable and multiply it to `prod`:

```
prod *= x % 10;
```

This line removes the last digit of `x`:

```
x = (x - x % 10) / 10;
```

First loop:

- Last digit = 6
- `prod` therefore equals 6
- `x` equals 32

Second loop:

- Last digit = 2
- `prod` therefore equals 6 * 2 = 12
- `x` equals 3

Third loop:

- Last digit = 3
- `prod` therefore equals 12 * 3 = 36
- `x` equals 0

```js
let x = 326;

let prod = 1;

while (x > 0) {
  prod *= x % 10;
  console.log({prod});
  x = (x - x % 10) / 10;
  console.log({x});
}

console.log(prod);
```